# Sorting the tuples of tuples in alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples
`[((A,B),2),((C,B),3)]`
Which I need to sort as

```
[((A,B),2),((B,C),3)]
```

I need all the tuples to be in alphabetical order using the `sorted()` method. I have used `key = lambda x : x[0]` but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a list of two-tuples containing a two-tuple (that you want to sort) and an integer. Sorting the list will not help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) within [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
In [3]: tups = [(('A','B'),2),(('C','B'),3)]

In [4]: [(sorted(t[0]), t[1]) for t in tups]
Out[4]: [(['A', 'B'], 2), (['B', 'C'], 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since @AmiTarovy solved it, but his method not include sorting on second element of outer tuple, when there is two or more `tuple` elements with same first element.

So here is another solution, that also make a sort for second argument of outer tuple.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> tups = [(('A','B'),2),(('C','B'),3), (('A','B'),1)]
>>> sorted(tups, key=itemgetter(0,1))
[(('A', 'B'), 1), (('A', 'B'), 2), (('C', 'B'), 3)]
```

If you want to sort only by first tuple

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> tups = [(('A','B'),2),(('C','B'),3), (('A','B'),1)]
>>> sorted(tups, key=itemgetter(0))
[(('A', 'B'), 2), (('A', 'B'), 1), (('C', 'B'), 3)]
```

**UPDATE**

Time consumption. Input data is 100 records of

```
((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase), random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)), random.randint(0,100))
```

*Results*:

@AmiTarovy answer with sorting *only by first element of tuple*

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import random; import string; tups = [((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase), random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)), random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(100)]" 'from operator import itemgetter; [(sorted(t[0]), t[1]) for t in tups]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.7 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.2 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 usec per loop
```

My answer with sorting *only by first element of tuple*

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import random; import string; tups = [((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase), random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)), random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(100)]" 'from operator import itemgetter; sorted(tups, key=itemgetter(0))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.1 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.6 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.9 usec per loop
```

My answer with *whole sorting*, but first element in priority

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import random; import string; tups = [((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase), random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)), random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(100)]" 'from operator import itemgetter; sorted(tups, key=itemgetter(0,1))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 61 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.6 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(('A','B'),2),(('C','B'),3)]
f=[(tuple(sorted(x[0])),x[1]) for x in l]
```

Output :

```
[(('A', 'B'), 2), (('B', 'C'), 3)]
```