# Sorting tuple of tuple in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[(('A', 'B'), 1.0), (('A', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'D'), 1.0), (('D', 'E'), 1.0), (('D', 'F'), 1.0), (('E', 'F'), 5.0), (('F', 'G'), 5.0), (('D', 'G'), 1.0)]
```

I need to sort this list in descending order on the numbers if in case of a tie I have to sort in the ascending order of alphabets

The final list should look something like this:

```
[(('E', 'F'), 5.0),(('F', 'G'), 5.0), (('A', 'B'), 1.0),(('A', 'C'), 1.0),(('B', 'C'), 1.0),(('B', 'D'), 1.0),(('D', 'E'), 1.0),(('D', 'F'), 1.0) (('D', 'G'), 1.0)]
```

Comment: cool story bro.

Comment: The hover-text for the downvote button begins, "This question does not show any research effort...".  To everyone who answered anyway:  Please don't [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729526) the [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: [How to Ask a Question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You should probably read that. Also this may help you pass this class (just getting an answer), but you're not gonna get a degree this way man.

Answer (score 6):

```
sorted(a_list,key=lambda x:(-x[-1],x[0]))
```

I guess... you should probably make an effort if you actually want to pass your class...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't as nice as Joran's solution, but since Timsort is stable, you could sort *twice*:

```
>>> my_list = [(('A', 'B'), 1.0), (('A', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'D'), 1.0), (('D', 'E'), 1.0), (('D', 'F'), 1.0), (('E', 'F'), 5.0), (('F', 'G'), 5.0), (('D', 'G'), 1.0)]
>>> sorted(sorted(my_list, key = lambda t:t[0]), key = lambda t:t[1],reverse=True)
[(('E', 'F'), 5.0), (('F', 'G'), 5.0), (('A', 'B'), 1.0), (('A', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'D'), 1.0), (('D', 'E'), 1.0), (('D', 'F'), 1.0), (('D', 'G'), 1.0)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works with dictionaries and uses its keys to do your work

```
testv = [(('A', 'B'), 1.0), (('A', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'D'), 1.0), (('D', 'E'), 1.0), (('D', 'F'), 1.0), (('E', 'F'), 5.0), (('F', 'G'), 5.0), (('D', 'G'), 1.0)]
testv_dict = {}
for element in testv:
    if element[1] in testv_dict.keys():
        testv_dict[element[1]].append(element)
    else:
        testv_dict[element[1]] = [element]
key_list = testv_dict.keys()
key_list.sort(reverse=True)
output_list = []
for key_i in key_list:
    output_list.extend(testv_dict[key_i])
```

Comment: This is way over-engineered.

Comment: that might be part of the point ...

Comment: Hoping not to come off as too critical, but you should rely on the `key` parameter to do these sorts of things. Also, I would look into `defaultdictionary` for this sort of idiom were your dictionary values will be another container that may or may not exist. It will be significantly faster than these checks. And finally, `if k in some_dict.keys()` is unecessary, you can simply use `if k in some_dict`